# Include assets from outside the rails app in asset_pipeline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, precompile

I am extending a existing code base and need a clear cut between the code that I have written and the existing code. I got it working for html-files by using this:

```
render :file => Rails.root.to_s.split('/')[0...-1].join('/')+'/my-extension/path/to/file/
```

(The first part cuts of the real Rails.root, allowing me to use a folder on the same level like the app)

Now I need to include additional files that need to be precompiled, e.g. SASS-CSS. I tried to add them to the asset pipeline like so:

```
config.assets.precompile += [Rails.root.to_s.split('/')[0...-1].join('/')+'/my-extension/app/assets/stylesheets/*.css']
```

or with a specific file name:

```
config.assets.precompile += [Rails.root.to_s.split('/')[0...-1].join('/')+'/my-extension/app/assets/stylesheets/overrides.css']
```

Neither of the two methods above have succeeded. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try creating a soft link from Rails root to the extension asset directory and include it in the asset path.

```
 $ cd your rails_project
 $ ln -s /path/to/extension/assets extension-assets
```

in config

```
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("extension-assets")
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up doing just now ;) was hoping for a cleaner solution though.